# How can I get Chrome Password Manager, LastPass, etc to remind me to use "Sign in with Google" and not username+password?

Tags: google-chrome, web, password-management, keychain, lastpass

### Background:

- Lots of sites have their own user registration systems and require you to login with a good ol' fashioned Username and Password, which password managers today handle (mostly) fine:

  - For example, 90% of sites on the world-wide-web have likely have [the usual login form](https://codepen.io/m3eu/pen/VwYBbwO).
- Lots of other sites use *delegated authentication* and don't have their own username and password box, instead they'll have a big fat "Sign in with Google" button, and/or "Sign in with Facebook", "Sign in with Apple" (if you're lucky), and others:

  - For example, Tinder (until very recently) *only* let you register and login using **only** Facebook:
    [image]
- Some sites let you use *either* delegated authentication *or* their own user registration system, but don't let you use *both* "Sign in with Google" *and* their own login form to access the same, single account.

  - For example, Mockaroo:
    [image]
- Other sites do let you use both delegated auth *and/or* their own user registration system to access the same user account.

  - For example, the StackOverflow Network:
    [image]

### The problem:

Most of the time I'll register for a site using their own registration system, so I have a username and password stored in my Google Chrome Password Manager and/or LastPass and/or Apple KeyChain.

But sometimes I'll register for a site using delegated authentication (i.e. *Sign-in with Google*), however if a site offers both their own registration form **and** delegated authentication then none of my password managers (not Chrome, not LastPass, nor Apple KeyChain) will remember the fact I used *Sign in with Google* **at all**).

...so one month I'll visit a site and register using Google, then come back in the future, often on a different device (but same Google Chrome account and/or other device with the same LastPass vault in) and not see any saved credentials in the password-safe, and then have-to guess if I registered using Google or manual registration, and 50% of the time I'm wrong and I end up with two separate accounts on the same site (one from my earlier Google sign-in, then this new one from manual registration).

And even then, I don't know *which* Google Account I used with delegated authentication. *Aieeegh*.

Unfortunately LastPass' "Add Password" form doesn't have an option or field that denotes "use *Sign-in with Google*, with Google Account *foo@bar.com*"), and burying unstructured data in memo fields just feels wrong.

Is it possible at all to have Google Chrome's Password Manager, or LastPass, or Apple KeyChain automatically remember (and automatically log me in!) when a site uses delegated authentication?

Answer (score 0):

A work-around in lastpass: create a password entry with username "use-google" and an empty password. Then when you visit the login page, "use-google" is autofilled, as your self-reminder to hit the google button. Similarly for "use-apple', etc.

Lastpass will complain about empty passwords, but you can disable or ignore those.